# Как правильно: "фальШстарт" или "фальстарт"?

Tags: орфография

Попалось в тексте написание "фальстарт" без Ш. Честно говоря, мне всегда казалось, что тут должна быть буква Ш (фальшивый старт). Правильно ли писать без Ш и, если да, то куда она делась?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ни разу не видел написание "фальшстарт", правильно только [фальстарт](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%F4%E0%EB%FC%F1%F2%E0%F0%F2).

Образовано слово от английского  "false start", где звука "ш" нет и в помине. Да и вообще даже если б было, при соединении похоже звучащие звуки, как правило, съедают друг друга, преобразуясь в единый звук. Поэтому сочетание "шс" могло бы сохранится, только если б играло смыслоразличительную роль или слово использовалось бы исключительно в академической среде, что в данном случае не наблюдаем.

Comment: У меня дети тоже иногда говорят "фальшстарт", но им в силу возраста можно. Хотя я исправляю. :) Интересно, что "ш" сохраняется в слове "фальшь" и др. По М.Фасмеру "фальшь" от немецкого falsch (через польский).

Comment: Фальшборт достаточно известен.

Comment: @grumant, "б" и "ш", достаточно различные звуки, а вот "с" и "ш" ассимилируются, например как в слове "сшить", где в начале произносится долгое "ш". Но в "сшить", это имеет дефереренцирующее значение. В "масштаб" произносим просто "ш", а написание сохранилось только из-за того, что до сравнительно недавнего времени слово употребляли только специалисты. Как произнести сочетание "шс", если не читать по слогам, я, вообще, представляю слабо.

@Надюшка, "фальшь" заимствовано с польского, а "фальстарт" с английского. В английском звука "ш" нету.

Comment: Я не спорю, просто интересно, что так в языке получается. :)

Comment: Интересно, должны быть еще какие-нибудь слова/выражения, пришедшие из разных языков и по-разному пишущиеся...

Comment: @Надюшка, есть даже слова пришедшие из одного и того же языка, но пишущиеся по разному (известь\асбест). Ещё можно вспомнить, варвар и барбарис и некоторые другие.

Comment: @Марк Из, глупости не говорите. В английском Ш есть. См. [wiki][1]: "she, ash, sure, ration". Другой вопрос, что это "ша" скорее всего немного отличается от русского "ша". К тому же сочетание "sh" с английского в русский переводится традиционно как "ш" (Тошиба, Мицубиши, Шрек).

 [1]:https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_pronunciation

Comment: @gecube, я имел в виду. что в английском выражении "false start" звука "ш" нету, прошу прощения, что не совсем точно выразился.

Comment: *Фальшборт* - а это не из английского.